# How do I use a model validation to ensure one field is >= another field in the same model in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp, validation, cakephp-1.2

I am trying to validate my model, I am using CakePHP 1.2.3.8166 and mysql 5

I have my model definied as it:

```
<?php
class Actividad extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'Actividad';
    var $validate = array('maxfield' => array(
        'rule'=> array('chkValue'),
        'message'=>'i2'
    ));

    function chkValue($data){
        return $data["maxfield"]>=$data["minfield"]
    }
}
```

My table has 2 fields; `maxfield` & `minfield`. I need to validate `maxfield` always >= `minfield` but I can't figure out how to check `minfield` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the value of "minfield" with $this->data['Actividad']['minfield']

Answer (score 0):

you already have the validation for maxfield, you just need to do the same thing with the minfield. so your $validate should be like this:

```
var $validate= array(
               'maxfield' => array(
                  'rule'=> 'chkValue',
                  'message'=>'i2'
                ),
               'minfield' => array(
                  'rule'=> 'chkValue',
                  'message'=>'i2'
               )   
        );
```

And by the way. 'rule' => 'nameOfValidationFunction'. no need to put in array.

Comment: Oh Thanks, I put it in a array, because some example put it as it, (passing parameters I guess)